# Content Overlapping on Website

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having an issue with content overwrapping on a website I'm working on for someone.

I've added the countdown timer/signup area at the top.  However, it's overlapping in all major browsers.  At first I thought it was an easy fix and just added a transparent image to knock down the content a bit more.  But, then I realized it fixed it for FireFox but was still overlapping on Chrome and Safari.

I think part of this is just that I've been looking at the code too long and am missing something simple.  If someone could post what needs to be added/changed, that would be great.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: I don't think the code for that page will really help but no problem, I'm about to add it to the original question.

Comment: You should provide the output generated not the raw PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the countdown contained within your header (`#header_wrapper`), which has its height set to 131px.

This means, the layout won't take the full size of the countdown into account.

You'll probably want to either move the countdown out of the header wrapper and into the content wrapper, or correct the height of the header appropriately.

Comment: WOW - I truly don't understand how I managed to miss that lol.  Thanks for the help Sebastian!